# Remove play button from Plotly R animation

Tags: r, animation, plotly, r-plotly

Is there a way to remove the "play" bottom in a plotly R animation? I just want to be able to have folks slide through the data using the slider, but I don't want a play function.

Here is the code:

```
g <- list(
  scope = 'usa',
  projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
  showland = TRUE,
  landcolor = toRGB("gray95"),
  subunitcolor = toRGB("gray85"),
  countrycolor = toRGB("gray85"),
  countrywidth = 0.5,
  subunitwidth = 0.5
)

fig <- plot_geo(dat, lat = ~Latitude, lon = ~Longitude, frame = ~Year) 

fig
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use

```
fig <- fig %>% animation_button(
  hide = T
)
```

Though I have never used plotly before so I am not sure. There is good documentation here: https://plotly.com/r/cumulative-animations/

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. The hide = TRUE is only a condition for animation_slider() not animation_button()

Comment: Hmm that is frustrating

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
fig <- fig %>% animation_button(visible=FALSE)
```